# How to access koa ctx object inside knex promise?

Tags: knex.js, koa

I'm querying the Database using KnexJS promise. I'm able to get the results in `async/await` but when I use Knex promise, I'm unable to access the `ctx` object inside `then` and `catch` part of the promise. The `console.log(results)` in showing results inside console.

Here's my code:

```
router.get('/profile', async ctx => {

  'http://localhost:8000/profile'

  ctx.knex
    .select().from('profile')

  .then(results => {
    console.error(results)
    this.body = results
  })

  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error)
    this.throw(500, "Inside Error")
  })

})
```

Comment: why would you not want to use Async/await?

Comment: because why not? @technogeek1995

Answer (score 1):

`ctx` should be available, since it's set in the enclosing scope.

But you must return `knex`'s promise from the router handler:

```
router.get('/profile', ctx => {
  return ctx.knex
      .select().from('profile')

      .then(results => {
        console.error(results)
        this.body = results
      })

      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
        this.throw(500, "Inside Error")
      })
});
```